# Passing XML to Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I am passing xml to a stored procedure and it is compiling but no row inserted into the database.

My code

```
foreach (int item in objDirectory.PhotoId)
{
   //roots = roots + "<row DirectoryId='"+objDirectory.DirectoryId+"'PhotoId='" +item+"'CreatedBy='"+"Admin"+"'ModifiedBy='"+"Admin"+"'/>";
   roots = roots + "<row DirectoryId= '" + objDirectory.DirectoryId + "' PhotoId='" + item + "' CreatedBy ='" + "Admin" + "' ModifiedBy ='" + "Admin" + "'/>";
}
PhotoIds = string.Format(PhotoIds, roots);
objDirectory.SavePhotoId(PhotoIds);
```

Save Method

```
public void SavePhotoId(string PhotoId)
{
    SqlTransaction tran = null;

    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] arParams = new SqlParameter[3];
        m_objConn = new SqlConnection(m_strConn);
        m_objConn.Open();
        tran = m_objConn.BeginTransaction();

        arParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@PhotoID", PhotoId);
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(tran, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertUpdatePhotIdInAlbum", arParams);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (m_objConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            m_objConn.Close();
            m_objConn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[InsertUpdatePhotIdInAlbum]
   @PhotoID xml=null
As
Begin
   set nocount on;

   if @PhotoID IS NULL
   Begin
       Return;
   End

   Declare @PhotoAlbumDetail TABLE (AlbumID int, PhotoId int, CreatedBy varchar(50), 
                                    ModifiedBy varchar(50))

   insert into @PhotoAlbumDetail(AlbumID, PhotoID, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy)
     select
         t.c.value('./@DirectoryId', 'int') as AlbumID,
         t.c.value('./@PhotoId', 'int') as PhotoID,
         t.c.value('./@CreatedBy', 'varchar(50)') as CreatedBy,
         t.c.value('./@ModifiedBy', 'varchar(50)') as ModifiedBy
     from 
         @PhotoID.nodes('/root/row') t(c);

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_PhotoAlbumDetail](AlbumID, PhotoId, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy)
      SELECT  
         p.AlbumID, p.PhotoId, p.CreatedBy, p.ModifiedBy 
      FROM 
         @PhotoAlbumDetail p  
End
```

Comment: We need to see a sample XML that you're passing in!

Comment: <root>
<row DirectoryId= '3' PhotoId='29' CreatedBy ='Admin' ModifiedBy ='Admin'/>
<row DirectoryId= '3' PhotoId='28' CreatedBy ='Admin' ModifiedBy ='Admin'/>
<row DirectoryId= '3' PhotoId='27' CreatedBy ='Admin' ModifiedBy ='Admin'/>
<row DirectoryId= '3' PhotoId='26' CreatedBy ='Admin' ModifiedBy ='Admin'/>
<row DirectoryId= '3' PhotoId='25' CreatedBy ='Admin' ModifiedBy ='Admin'/>
</root>

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Works just fine for me .... I find the name `@PhotoID` for an XML structure horribly bad (`ID` always implies an identifier, usually a number - use something else), and I don't understand what the reason is to first insert the rows extracted from the XML into a table variable and only in a second step into the actual table....... but the code seems to work just fine for me.